# Array Values Based on Index Contained in Another Array

Tags: python, arrays, matlab

To preface this, I'm a very weak programmer and am trying to learn Python.  I have a MATLAB .m file that I'm trying to translate into Python.  The MATLAB portion I'm having trouble with is:

```
R(i+1,1)=mod(sum(b(a)),2)
    where
b = [4 5 6]
a = [3 1]
```

Background: the number of columns in b is the maximum value contained in a.  I can input any array for a and b, as long as b is sized properly.

Based on the above example, I know the intent would be (b[3]+b[1])mod(2) = (6 + 4)mod(2) = 0.  I'm just not sure how to achieve this in Python.  If I can provide any additional details, please let me know.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
r[i+1,1]=sum([b[x-1] for x in a]) % 2
```

the [  ] creates a list and 
b[x-1] takes care if the indexing since indexes in python starts from 0. In simple words for every x in a, calculate b[x-1] and then create a list from them and then sum the list and finally take the mod 2.

where b and a are defined as
    b=[4,5,6]
    a=[3,1]
and r can be a list of lists, thus making it a matrix.

let me know if you cant understand it...

Comment: This worked fantastically well.  I changed R[i+1,1] to R[i+1,0] due to MATLAB vs. Python indexing but otherwise it works exactly as I'd like.  Thanks a ton for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:

```
import numpy
a = numpy.array([3, 1])
b = numpy.array([4, 5, 6, 9]) #keep in mind that python index starts at 0
R[i+1, 1] = numpy.mod(sum(b[a]), 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/).  `numpy` is the best way to transition from MATLAB to Python and uses a lot of the same syntax.  Also keep in mind that `numpy` starts indexing at 0, and not 1 like in MATLAB.  As such, you'd need to change `a` so that you subtract all indices by 1 as you are using this to index into `b`.  You would also need to change how you're indexing into `R` so that 0 is the beginning index, not 1.

Assuming that `R` is also a `numpy` array, do:

```
import numpy as np

# Place other code here...
#...
#...

a = np.array([2, 0]) # change, or you can do a = np.array([3, 1]) - 1
b = np.array([4, 5, 6, 9])
R[i, 0] = np.mod(np.sum(b[a]), 2)
```